# Why does not array get updated on successful delete?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I store a user with field called **myMovies** in firestore. I am able to successfully add a movie in this array but when I try to remove one it does not work and the logic behind the adding and removing is similar.

It does show me that the array is successfully updated but in firestore the element I delete is still there.

Here is my code:

```
 @Override
public void removeMovie(Movie movie, FirebaseAddMovieListener listener) {
    firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid()).update("myMovies", FieldValue.arrayRemove(movie))
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    listener.onSuccess("SUCCESS");
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    listener.onFailure(e.getMessage() + e + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            });

}
```

**Add Movie**

```
 @Override
   public void addMovieToUserLibrary(Movie movie, FirebaseAddMovieListener 
listener) {

    firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid()).update("myMovies", FieldValue.arrayUnion(movie))
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    listener.onSuccess("SUCCESS");
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    listener.onFailure(e.getMessage() + e + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            });

}
```

Database Structure
[image: database]

Comment: Should  "movie" not be in " " ?, But the code looks fine, maybe is where you are executing the method, also check your spelling for your collection and such

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Besides that, what are the values of `Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getCurrentUser()` and `movie`? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I have added the database structure, also movie is an object I want to delete and getCurrentUser is the user who is currently logged in, I want to delete a movie from his list of movies.

Comment: @RubenMeiring spelling is all correct,  I have the same logic for arrayUnion when I add an object and it works fine.

Comment: Can you post the arrayUnion Code so we can compare them might see the issue there

Comment: @RubenMeiring yes, just did it.

Comment: I can see no problem with your code, did you check your error log?

Comment: There is nothing there.

Comment: You are storing objects within that array. So please check the duplicate to see how you can remove an item from an array of objects.

Comment: @AlexMamo The duplicate you marked is removing by array index, while OP here seems to be using `Movie` as far as I can see.

Comment: @Fiphe: can you show how you populate the `movie` to remove it?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh, yes. Looking forward to seeing OP's answer.

Comment: Please add what Frank van Puffelen asked for and please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: I have found the issue. Even though it did not show me any exception while checking my code I saw that one of my fields in the model class had a capital letter while the rest had small letters. That fixed it, though, adding an object to the array worked even with the capital letter which is strange.